# How to get intersection observer to correctly trigger with responsive layout

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a website with a responsive layout, doesn't use media queries. On the page in question, I have a section of text, then an SVG (which resizes responsively, so height is not fixed), then some more text.

What I want to happen is that when the user scrolls past the first text block and the SVG is nearer the top of the screen, the observer fires (the SVG adds some elements).

It works, but I have had to set a compromise negative bottom root margin that works mostly over all viewport sizes. It currently fires by observing the headline below the image.

But I want to make it a bit more precise, so that it fires when the SVG is X pixels from the top, no matter what height the SVG is.

```
  <p>some content</p>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 510 185" id='graph'>
<h3 id='next'>next section</h3>
<p>more text</p>

    <script>
        const target = document.querySelector('#next');
        const options = {
            root: null,
            rootMargin: '0px 0px -50% 0px',
            threshold: 1
        }
        function handleIntersection(entries) {
          entries.map((entry) => {
            if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                document.querySelectorAll(".initialhide").forEach(elem => elem.style.display="revert");
            } 
          });
        }
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection,options);
        observer.observe(target);
    </script>
```

The page in question is: [my blog page](https://stuart-mcmillan.com/blog/running/6months.html)

Comment: Your blog will change (or be gone) over time. That is why it is custom to include (all) code in your question. Use the [<>] button in the SO editor to create a working snippet. tnx

Comment: Please show how you have set the options on the observer, preferably with a runnable snippet.

Comment: Thanks, was in too much of a rush and doing it on mobile. Hopefully clearer now.